# Passing data from System.Windows.Forms WebBrowser to separate web page

Tags: vb.net, web, webbrowser-control

In my windows form application I need to show a map. In order to do that I'm using **System.Windows.Forms WebBrowser**. I was able to load the default map.

What my issue is, map information such as Latitude and Longitude is available in win forms application. So I need to pass them to my web page which is PURE HTML AND JAVA SCRIPT.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which Map Provider are you using? i.e. Google Maps..

Comment: Baidu map.......